# Killing a comet zombie

Tags: process, kill, zombie-process

I have a zombie process that is changing its PID, which is increasing. Is it possible to kill a process with PID greater than N?

Comment: What makes you think it is changing it's PID? You can't kill zombies, they are already dead. I suspect that the process is becoming a zombie, getting reaped and another instance is then becoming a zombie, hence the increasing PID.

Comment: Can you add some `ps` output how it keeps changing the pid?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
pkill -f string
```

where string is a part of the process name

Answer (score 3):

**You can't kill a zombie**. As the name indicates, it's dead. A zombie is not a real process, it's only an entry in the process table, waiting for the parent to take notice.

**A process doesn't change its process ID**. If you see new process IDs appear, it's because something is spawning them.

If the process you're killing is being monitored, the monitoring program sees that the process has died, so it starts a new instance. However, with a monitoring program, the process would not be a zombie, since the monitor would be watching its child.

Since you're seeing a zombie, it has a parent which isn't paying attention to its child. Check what the parent process is: run `ps -o ppid -p 1234` where 1234 is the PID of the zombie, then `ps -p 2345` where 2345 is the PID of the parent. Then decide what you want to do based on the parent is, e.g. configure it to stop spawning that child.

Answer (score 1):

The command `pkill` may be available on your system. Instead of a PID, it takes a process name pattern as argument which allows you to designate the process to kill by their name instead of by PID, for instance if you would like to terminate the `httpd` process:

```
pkill http
```

In case of need, it can also take the `-9` parameter to brutally halt the process.

By default it will affect all processes matching the pattern given as parameter. I therefore recommend you to use before the `pgrep` command with the same pattern as parameter which will list you all matching processes so you are sure to not kill unexpected processes.

These commands accept a variety of supplementary filters to restrict the selection upon different criterion, do not hesitate to check their man page to grab the filters applicable to your situation if needed.